# How to set a integer for a hidden_field in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two variables like `Question_type` and `Answer_type` in JavaScript.

I have a `hidden_field` with no value, I want to insert a `value` to the `hidden_field` by checking the conditions of `Question_type`and `Answer_type` like the following:

```
If Question_type == 'A' && Answer_type == 'B' {
    hidden_field = 1;
} else if Question_type == 'A' && Answer_type !== 'B' {
    hidden_field = 2;
} else if Question_type !== 'A' && Answer_type == 'B' {
    hidden_field = 3;
{ else if Question_type !== 'A' && Answer_type !== 'B' {
    hidden_field = 4;
}
```

How to do this concept by short form or the clean method in JavaScript? Any JSfiddle example would be more appreiciated.

Comment: *"How to do this concept by short form..."* Are you asking how to shorten this code, or how to set the value of the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option to shorten the code:

```
var isA = Question_type == 'A',
    isB = Answer_type == 'B';

hidden_field =  isA &&  isB ? 4 :
                isA && !isB ? 3 :
               !isA &&  isB ? 2 :
                              1;
```

---

Here's another:

```
if (Question_type == 'A')
    if (Answer_type == 'B')
        hidden_field = 4;
    else
        hidden_field = 3;
else
    if (Answer_type == 'B')
        hidden_field = 2;
    else
        hidden_field = 1;
```

Comment: @Vinay: I updated the answer *(at the top)* since we really don't need to test the last condition. If the first 3 fail, then the last will always pass, so `0` would never have been set.

Comment: yeah here its shows the error for the last statement. 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( '

Comment: @Vinay: Make sure you copied the code correctly. There aren't any SyntaxErrors in the code above.

Comment: @Vinay: I prefer the first example *if* it can be done cleanly. If the code starts becoming a mess or unclear, then I use `if` statements.

Comment: One more doubt. Here the question_type is defined somewhere down the page inside the other function. How to define that globally and call it anywhere in the jsfile?

Comment: @Vinay: The safe and proper way to do it is to make it a property of `window`. Like this: `window.question_type = "foo"`. All global variables can be accessed from the `window` object.

Answer (score 4):

Use `getElementById` to get hidden by Id:

```
 var hidden_field = document.getElementById('HiddenFieldId');
 hidden_field.value = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified code: If should be if and conditions must be inside '()'.

```
if (Question_type == 'A' && Answer_type == 'B') {
     $("#hidden_field").val( 1);
} else if (Question_type == 'A' && Answer_type !== 'B') {
    $("#hidden_field").val(  2);
} else if (Question_type !== 'A' && Answer_type == 'B') {
     $("#hidden_field").val( 3);
{ else if (Question_type !== 'A' && Answer_type !== 'B') {
       $("#hidden_field").val( 4);
}
```

Comment: what does it mean by inside (). I am new to javascript. Please define ?

Comment: @MalSu he has jQuery tag in question.

Comment: @Vinay if condition1 && condition2 is invalid in JavaScript it should be if(condition1 && condition2).

Comment: @Shusl and Rails as well, but he's new to JS. I don't believe showing a jQuery answer to a basic JS problem is the correct approach. Although for completeness the answer should remain.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ternary operator` may help shortening the code:

```
if (Question_type == 'A') {
    hidden_field.value = Answer_type == 'B' ? 1 : 2;
} else {
    hidden_field.value = Answer_type == 'B' ? 3 : 4;
}
```

[check out this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zainshaikh/s3ubH/)

Answer (score -1):

Give some ID to hidden field, and set it's value.